# Schedule multiple crons in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, cron

I am trying to run multiple jobs in Laravel at different times. This is the code:

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    $schedule->command('emails:send')->dailyAt('08:00');
    $schedule->command('emails:evening-status')->dailyAt('17:00');
    $schedule->command('email:weekly-report')->weekly()->mondays()->at('08:00');
}
```

The problem here is that only the first command `emails:send` works. The other commands don't work at the specified time. However, when I run them manually they work fine.

What is it that I am missing?

Comment: Same problem here using Laravel 5.1.31

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33998179/laravel-5-1-task-scheduling-command-issue

Comment: Working just fine with Laravel 5.1.34

Comment: Also keep in mind, that this scheduling works not on server time, but on application time. So double check what timezone using Your application or just type "date('H:i')" in artisan tinker so be sure, that application have same time as Your machine.

Comment: @GiedriusKiršys I had two `dailyAt` with the same time. First one was running, second did not. I guess I will try the update. Thanks.

Comment: Do you call it from cronjob at 17:00? I see how 3rd one could fail if it takes more than a minute for 'emails:send', but the 2nd one should work.

Comment: Do you have an accepted answer? I also am experiencing this issue...

Answer (score 2):

Similar situation, except that I am calling a method for each cron using `call`, for example:

```
$schedule->call('\App\Http\Controllers\comm\commCron::abc');
$schedule->call('\App\Http\Controllers\comm\commCron::xyz');
```

I had the same problem, later realised first cron was calling an `exit` at some point of error.

So please make sure none of the crons retuls in `exit` or `die()`. Just `return false` instead (if you need to).

Comment: The reminding of not using `exit` or `dd` or `die()` is important. I solved my schedule problem with this reminding.

Answer (score 2):

I think you may need to look at  your actual server cron configuration. Laravel scheduler requires the server cron to be run every minute for all schedules to run at the desired time. You may just have the cron running at 8.00am every day instead of every minute.

It may be worth a check, I know I had difficulty with the same issue when I first started scheduling.

When using the scheduler, you only need to add the following Cron entry to your server. If you do not know how to add Cron entries to your server, consider using a service such as Laravel Forge which can manage the Cron entries for you:

```
* * * * * php /path-to-your-project/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

This Cron will call the Laravel command scheduler every minute. When the schedule:run command is executed, Laravel will evaluate your scheduled tasks and runs the tasks that are due.

Answer (score 1):

It's been 4 years since this question added, but I hope my answer still can help anyone. In my case (adapted from your case), I just added some conditional cases with the `Carbon` package from Laravel in my `Kernel.php`.

In my case, I want to run 3 schedulers. Two schedulers will run once every Monday at 8 AM and 5 PM and one else will run once every day. And this is how I make the condition.

```
public function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
   if(Carbon::now()->format('N') == '1')  //check if today is Monday
   {
      if(Carbon::now()->format('G') == '8')  //check if now is 8 AM
      {
         $schedule->command('first:command')->everyMinute();
      }
      if(Carbon::now()->format('G') == '17') //check if now is 5 PM
      {
         $schedule->command('second:command')->everyMinute();
      }
   }

   $schedule->command('another:command')->dailyAt('08:00')->withoutOverlapping();
}
```

Then, you can set up your cron job in the server to run hourly. The `another:command` schedule will not run 24 times a day because I have added the `withoutOverlapping()` method, and it only will run at 8 AM.
See this [laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/scheduling) about scheduling and this [PHP docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) about date-time format if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

If second comand is not working:

```
$schedule->command('emails:evening-status')
             ->dailyAt('17:00');
```

you can insert only one line of code that print current date in some file eg. "test.txt" then check in wanted time if file is created. If file is created you can conclude that something if wrong with code in script that is scheduled.

Answer (score 0):

Use queue for job processing

on cron, add all jobs to queue

Run multiple queue workers

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code:

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
        $schedule->command('emails:send')
                 ->dailyAt('08:00')->withoutOverlapping();

        $schedule->command('emails:evening-status')
                 ->dailyAt('17:00')->withoutOverlapping();

        $schedule->command('email:weekly-report')
                 ->weekly()->mondays()->at('08:00')->withoutOverlapping();
}
```

Above code just execute without overlapped. You can get more idea about [prevent overlapping](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/scheduling#preventing-task-overlaps).

Let me know if you still facing same.

Comment: What has overlapping to do with this?

Answer (score 0):

We ran intro similar issues when using Laravel's built-in scheduling module.

In our case, the first command was silently failing and preventing the subsequent scheduled commands from being run.

As a quick test, try changing the order of the commands such that emails:send is at the bottom and see if that works. In general, catch any Exceptions that may be thrown and it should fix the issue.

Answer (score -1):

if you need use Laravel Schedule Use This code

```
    $schedule = new Schedule();
    $schedule->command('emails:send')
             ->dailyAt('08:00')->withoutOverlapping();

    $schedule = new Schedule();
    $schedule->command('emails:evening-status')
             ->dailyAt('17:00')->withoutOverlapping();

    $schedule = new Schedule();
    $schedule->command('email:weekly-report')
             ->weekly()->mondays()->at('08:00')->withoutOverlapping();
```

but may be this way is wrong, advise to use Laravel artisan Command and put that cammand on host cron jobs