# Laravel 5.1 Task Scheduling command issue

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I am trying to execute two console commands.Below is my two commands in my **Kernel.php**

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    $schedule->command('users:get')->everyMinute();

    $schedule->command('users:update')->dailyAt('01:00');
}
```

When I run **php artisan schedule:run**, Only the command which is/are scheduled as **everyMinute** is scheduled.

> Running scheduled command: '/usr/bin/php5' 'artisan' users:get > /dev/null 2>&1 &

If I change the **dailyAt** to **everyMinute** for the second command, both are scheduled as shown below

> Running scheduled command: '/usr/bin/php5' 'artisan' users:get > /dev/null 2>&1 &
>
> Running scheduled command: '/usr/bin/php5' 'artisan' users:update > /dev/null 2>&1 &

Comment: you are mentioning dailyAt('01:00'),so when your time will 01.00 and you run php artisan schedule:run that time this command will execute,otherwise not

Answer (score 0):

`php artisan schedule:run` will run the scheduled commands, not list them.

So, if you run the scheduled commands before `01:00` the `users:update` command will not be scheduled yet and will not be ran.

Comment: is there any artisan command for showing the list of sheduled commands

Comment: `php artisan list` will list all artisan commands, and there's none that list scheduled commands. What's your goal with this? If you want to check the schedules from the terminal you could just `cat app/Console/Kernel.php`. Or if you want to get fancy you could probably cobble together a shell script that gets only the relevant lines with with `grep` and `head` or maybe `sed`?